# Read registry files in Windows "config" directory from a backup?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I have a backup of a computer and I need to get some information from its registry files. I have the files from the registry, but cannot find a tool or anything to let me view this information, just as I would on a machine using regedit.

Any ideas?  I do not want restore the computer backup - do I have any options?

Answer (score 11):

MiTeC's [**Windows Registry Recovery**](http://www.mitec.cz/wrr.html) can read the files and even export them into REGEDIT4 format like a normal registry backup.

> MiTeC Windows Registry File Viewer is
>   a viewer for Windows registry hives of
>   all (e.g. NTUSER.DAT, SYSTEM.1ST, SAM,
>   etc. - not .reg files). It displays
>   the file content in a tree view,
>   similar to the standard RegEdit
>   display and includes features like
>   registry searching, dumping and
>   exporting to REGEDIT4 format. The
>   program also allows you to explore the
>   NT/2k/XP security records. In order to
>   view most of the supported files, you
>   need to create a copy of them first,
>   as they cannot be used while they are
>   used by the NT/2000/XP system.

[image]

Windows Registry Recovery is freeware.

Answer (score 0):

The [BartPE](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/peboot.htm) software will probably let you do it (see the instructions for the 'Scenario' on that page on how to load a registry.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @CanadianLuke You were correct.  I'm going through old answers and now the BartPE seems to be gone :-(